# Save x-editable values into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

How can I save x-editable form values to mysql database using php and jquery.

Here is my link:

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter Username">John</a>

<script>
   //editables 
    $('#username').editable({
           url: '',
           type: 'text',
           pk: 1,
           name: 'username',
           title: 'Enter username'
    });      
</script>
```

In the same page I tried

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
echo $_POST['username'];
}
```

But I am not getting the value....

[image]

Comment: Can you describe more then `its not working.`? Are you sending the value? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access an other POST Key.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```